# How to push data to array using ajax

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, post

I have a page listing products - each having an add to cart button. Using the data attribute in the button, I need push the offerId string into an existing array. The expected result after adding multiple products to the cart would be to return an array with all the offerIds. Currently, if I print_r the offerIdArray, it only shows the latest button's offerId.

Thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".addtocart button").click(function () {
        var offerIdArray = [];
        var offerId = $(this).attr("data-offerId");
        $.post("controller/create-cart.php", {
            offerIdArray: offerIdArray.push(offerId)
        },
        function (data) {
            $('body').append(data);
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT: Below is my working code - thanks to @brroshan. I also had to push the offerId to the offerIdArray before I could sent the array via post.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    offerIdArray = [];                                
    $(".addtocart button").click(function () {                    
        var offerId = $(this).attr("data-offerId"); 
        offerIdArray.push(offerId);                    
        $.post("controller/create-cart.php",
            {                                
                offerIdArray: offerIdArray
            },
            function (data) {
                $('body').append(data);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show return value of $(this).attr("data-offerId");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you create a new array everytime the `".addtocart button"` is clicked. Just declare your array outside the click handler and it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var offerIdArray = [];       // <--
      $(".addtocart button").click(function () {

        var offerId = $(this).attr("data-offerId");

        $.post("controller/create-cart.php", {
            offerIdArray: offerIdArray.push(offerId)
        },
        function (data) {
            $('body').append(data);
        });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move offerIdArray outside the function. Right now it's a local variable. So you're recreating it every time you call that function. You need a global variable. I hope that helps.